# Asterisk coming up in Jupyter Notebook with a specific code

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I am using Jupyter Notebook, I keep getting the asterisk that indicates the kernel is busy when I run this specific code:

```
var = 2
var += 1
var_rem = var % 3

while var_rem == 0:
    var += 2

print var
```

In order to give some context, I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Define a new number variable and choose a value for it. If the
>   variable + 1 can be divided by three, increase the variable by two.
>   Test by printing the final value of the variable and varying the
>   initial value of that same variable.

I have tried restarting the kernel as it was recommended in front of the asterisk issue but it doesn't work. What is specific about this code that the kernel cannot process it? How do I then solve the exercise?

**Note:** First post around here, I hope it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code results in an infinite loop. Your variable `var_rem` does not change its value in the loop, therefore it runs forever (because it remains `0`)

You have to recalculate the while condition within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statement your logic is wrong. Try this...

```
var = 2
if ((var + 1) % 3) == 0:
    var +=2
    print var
else:
  print 'Not divisible by 3'
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, now that I re-read the formulation of the exercise, it is asking to increase the variable, not the variable + 1. It is also tidier than my code.